# Are you able to change mayors on Animal Crossing New Leaf?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Okay, so I bought Animal Crossing a few days ago and my brother decided to start playing it before I did, and now he's the mayor and I'm not. I have progressed with the other account that's not a Mayor, not knowing that I wasn't the mayor, and now I just found out that I can't do anything. Is there any way I can transfer the data from one character to another? Can I at least change the name of the first character?

Comment: Your avatar... disturbing is not enough to describe it...

Comment: I think it stinks you cant switch mayors. I had the exact same prob with my brother! Well maybe the buying a new New Leaf would work and moving ur villager to the town. Nintendo probably should of thought about putting a "Are you the mayor" option in the train scene. Then younger brothers or girlfriends could say no and then have the next player say Yup. Well too late for that I guess...

Comment: @MoetheShmoe but then it would ruin the whole concept of the story. In the beginning the "Mayor" is taken by surprise because the residents believe that (s)he is the mayor. Even so, the person who plays first deserves to be the mayor, no?

Answer (score 3):

If you get another copy of Animal Crossing: New Leaf, take another 3DS then go talk to Isabelle at the town hall and say you want to move out and you move to the other game or you can simply talk to Isabelle when you start the game and when she asks if you want to start choose "I need help first" then say you want to destroy the town then say your sure then choose new player move in explain everything to Rover and then when you you get off the train you're the mayor hope this helps oh almost forgot you could also just play another Animal Crossing New Leaf. Or you play as a villager

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of switching mayor powers between users. I have the same problem with my gf.

In the game if you really want to progress in the game you MUST be playing with the mayor most of the time so you get public works requests and everything.

As I said there is no way of transfering the mayor powers or switching it so you either restart the whole thing or play on his character. You can always mail him everything you have and play his character if you've progressed too much to reset...

Hope this helps. I had the same problem with my gf so now I'm just playing her character and mine at same time when she's not playing xD